# Do I need to construct a function $g$? Royden, Real Analysis, 2.6. item 40.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

problem:
[image]
I am letting $g(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x\in F$} \\[2ex]
\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}(x)+\gamma, & \text{if $x\notin F$}
\end{cases}$
and let $\gamma\in\Bbb{R}$ be the "y-intercept"(I'm thinking how to write this formally) and let $b$ be the least upperbound of all elements less than or equal to $a$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

However the solution manual provided
[image]
Question: Why do I need to mention $F$ is closed and $F^c$ is open and they're the union of a countable collection of open intervals? Also, the manual only mentioned to take $g$ to be linear, but, for me, I think the author of the solutions was simply not trying to be careful since the exercise is a bit trivial?

Comment: What is your $\gamma$, what is your $n$, your $a$, your $b$? Actually, what is the problem statement?

Comment: I just edited. I rushed posting my question

Comment: I want to say that $\gamma$ is the "y-intercept" but thought it was too informal.

Comment: The problem is based on the fact that you can extend the function by joining the graph of $f$ at end points of $F$ with straight lines. End points of $F$ are those which are not in the interior of $F$. To make the argument precise it consider the complement of $F$ and then joins those intervals in $F^{c} $ by line segments.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you believe to have defined $g$ for the case $F=[1,2]\cup [3,4]\cup [5,\infty)\cup \{\,\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}\,\}\cup \{0\}$ and $f(x)=\sin x$ for $x\in F$? And if you believe that you do not need that $F$ is closed, how does your $g$ work for $F=(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\frac1x$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Yes I understand the connecting of end points, hence, the way I defined $g$. But is it necessary?

Comment: I don't see any other way to extend it. Better try with an example $F=[1, 2]\cup [3,4]$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Letting $a$ and $b$ to be in $F$ $g(x)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}(x)+\gamma$ seems to work for me. Does it? And for $F=(0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)=1/x$ it does not because $F$ is not closed.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Your $a$ and $b$ are underspecified. And if you think that you do not need to mention that $F$ is closed, you cannot use "because $F$ is not closed" against  $1/x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some, the hint given with the problem statement counts already a full solution, for others, the solution in the solution manual is only an extended informal hint. I suppose you want to make the definition of $g$ sufficiently formal. I think this could be done (note that the definition of $g$ does not yet comprise the proof of the desired properties of $g$):

For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $u(x)=\inf(F\cap [x,\infty))$ and $v(x)=\sup(F\cap(-\infty,x])$. Note that

- $u(x)\in F\cup\{+\infty\}$ and $v(x)\in F\cup\{-\infty\}$
- at least one of $u(x),v(x)$ is finite unless $F=\emptyset$
- $v(x)<x<u(x)$ for $x\notin F$ (because $F$ is closed!)
- $u(y)=u(x)$, $v(y)=v(x)$ for $y$ with $v(x)<y<u(x)$, i.e.,  $u,v$ are constant in a neighbourhood of $x$ for $x\notin F$

For $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\in\Bbb R$ with $x_1<x_2$ let 
$$h_{x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2}(x)=\frac{y_2(x-x_1)+y_1(x_2-x)}{x_2-x_1}.$$
Then $h_{x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2}$ is a continuos function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $h_{x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2}(x_1)=y_1$ and $h_{x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2}(x_2)=y_2$. Now let
$$ g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&x\in F\\
h_{v(x),u(x),f(v(x)),f(u(x))}(x)&x\notin F, -\infty<v(x)<u(x)<\infty\\
f(u(x))&x\notin F, v(x)=-\infty,u(x)<\infty\\
f(v(x))&x\notin F, u(x)=\infty,v(x)>-\infty\\
42&F=\emptyset
\end{cases}$$